# Swift - Adicionar botão mostrar senha

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho um campo de texto, já consegui incluir ao lado direito uma imagem, ao clicar neste gostaria de revelar a senha, porém, não estou conseguindo chegar a este resultado. O código atual é:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var usuarioOuEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var senha: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mostrar: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView();
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
        senha.rightView = imageView
        senha.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Como faço para ao clicar na imagem ser disparada uma outra função?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui algo próximo ao que eu quero utilizando o código:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var usuarioOuEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var senha: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mostrarOcultar: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "mostrarOcultarSenha")
        mostrarOcultar.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        mostrarOcultar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func mostrarOcultarSenha()
    {
        if senha.secureTextEntry == false
        {
            mostrarOcultar.image = UIImage(named: "botao_ocultar.png")
            senha.secureTextEntry = true
        }
        else
        {
            mostrarOcultar.image = UIImage(named: "botao_mostrar")
            senha.secureTextEntry = false
        }
    }
//... 
}
```

Mas o problema é que quando clico na UIImageView responsável por revelar a senha a mesma é mostrada com outro tamanho e estilo de fonte, o cursor fica piscando longe da fonte em razão da formatação. Veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz um teste e tive o mesmo problema. Pelo que vi isso é um bug to UITextField http://www.openradar.appspot.com/20345712

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar toques no *ImageView* você pode adicionar um *TapGestureRecognizer*. Exemplo:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"handleImageTap:")
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

}

func handleImageTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   senha.text = "senhaUltraSecreta"
}
```

Comment: tentei algo parecido, porém não teve efeito.